# Getting data from fulfilled Q promise object in node REPL

Tags: node.js, promise, q, node-repl

Consider this simple Q promise object:

```
nesh> var p = functionThatReturnsPromise();
```

The REPL is kind enough to output the promise's state and value if I go:

```
nesh> p
{ state: 'fulfilled',
  value: 
   {
     // (data properties)
   }
}
```

Suppose I indeed waited for the promise to fulfill, I can't get the value nor the state directly by `p.value` or `p.state`.

I can do something like:

```
nesh> var data
undefined
nesh> p.then(function(_data) { data = _data })
```

yet it feels clumsy and uncomfortable for fluent REPL workflow.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not "clumsy" or "uncomfortable", that's the intended behaviour for promises. `p` only holds the reference to the promise, if you want to check the value then you use `.then` and can inspect the value there.

Comment: I know what the intended behavior is. Again, I'd like to have a more fluent workflow within the REPL. If I type the promise object's name and it outputs a magical object { state: ... , value: ... }, then asking access to it is not too much to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var p = functionThatReturnsPromise();
```

Promises do have the `state` and `value` defined, but for accessing that you need to use the `valueOf()` function over this.

```
p.valueOf() ==> promise value
p.inspect() ==> { state: 'fulfilled', value: 'data' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

p.then(function (value) { debugger; });

Then "continue" -- execution will stop when promise is fulfilled and callback is called. Note however, it seems to freeze, node 0.12.4, though I'd think this was a node bug -- perhaps will work for you.